# Selecting certain strings from a txt file, VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I'm trying to find out how I can select certain strings from an opened txt file in VB6.
I already managed to get the file opened, and have assigned it to variable (not sure if that will work). The txt file that has been opened also includes other information which is irrelevant, hence the need to create a new file with the relevant info.
I kind of wrote some sort of an algorithm, it's not very good though :P

```
'READ Line 01
'REPEAT
   'IF line begins with "studentname=" then
      'Copy to new textbox, in new textbox/variable create new line
   'ELSE If line begins with "studentID="
      'Copy to new textbox, in new textbox/variable create 2 new lines
   'ENDIF
   'READ next line
'UNTIL end of text is reached
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 3):

This is an example code for your question:

```
Filename$="myfilename.txt"       'This row assigns to variable Filename$
                                 'the name of your file, example: 
                                 '"myfilename.txt"

Open Filename$ For Input As #1   'This row opens the file Filename$ 

  Do While Not EOF(1)            'This row inits the loop to read all 
                                 'lines in your file and loop ends when
                                 'there is not others lines to read

   Line Input #1, line$          'This row inserts on variable line$ a
                                 'line of your file

   If mid(line$,1,12)="studentname=" then 'In this row the command mid 
                                          ' extracts the first 12 chars 
                                          'of line and verify if is 
                                          'equal to "studentname="

    Text1.Text=mid(line$,13)     'Is equal? Then In this line mid 
                                 'extracts from 13° char
                                 'to last char and set it on Text1  

   ElseIf mid(line$,1,10)="studentID=" then 'Is not equal to 
                                            ' "studentname="? Then 
                                            ' verify if the first 10 
                                            ' chars are equals to 
                                            ' "studentID="

    Text2.Text=mid(line$,11)     'Is equal? Then In this line mid 
                                 'extracts from 11° char
                                 'to last char and set it on Text2

    '... You can insert others ElseIf conditions 

   End If                         

  Loop                        'Loop

Close #1                      'This row closes file
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could you explain what each part is doing, and how I can incorporate it to work with my code? Thanks again